# A branch from which I created my branch is removed

Tags: git

I have a master branch.

I have a feature1 branch created from master.

I created a feature2 branch created from feature1.

I know at some point feature1 is going to be merged into master and removed.

Assuming I won't push or pull untill then, what actions am I supposed to take when that happens ?

___________ EDIT

I assume feature1 will be rebased from master before being merged.

Comment: It depends on how `feature1` gets merged into `main` (which is preferred to `master` these days, fwiw).  If it's squashed or rebased  the history will change and the commits from `feature1` in `feature2` will be rewritten; you can fix `feature2` by rebasing atop `main` and removing the old commits from `feature2`'s history (which will get them from `main`'s history instead).  If you do a merge commit without rewriting history, the old commits will still be present and you won't need to do anything.

Comment: Either way, your `feature2` branch stands alone without `feature1`.  A branch is a history of commits; the fact that those commits came from a branch that's since been deleted isn't relevent for `feature2`.

Comment: Thank you for reply. If commits from feature1 in feature2 are rewritten during rebase, I will see no changes in my commit logged after I do a "git pull" on my side ?

Comment: If `feature1` is going to be rebased into **master** then also rebase `feature2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @TTT's answer *generally* **but** I do want to bring up the case when `feature1` has been removed or rebased. Given that it's an independent branch, you cannot just assume that the branch will be there where it was when you want to run a command.... say that you start from here:

```
* III (feature2, origin/feature2)
* HHH
* GGG
* FFF (feature1, origin/feature1)
* EEE
* DDD
* CCC (main, origin/main)
* BBB
* AAA
```

And let's assume that each of the local branches is tracking its remote counterpart.

So.... what happens if the developer of `feature1` decides to *rebase* `feature1` on top of new revisions of `main`.... so, you fetch and you find this:

```
* FFF' (origin/feature1)
* EEE'
* DDD'
* KKK (origin/main)
* JJJ
| * III (feature2, origin/feature2)
| * HHH
| * GGG
| * FFF (feature1)
| * EEE
| * DDD
|/
* CCC (main)
* BBB
* AAA
```

If you are lucky enough to have a local copy of `feature1`, then running this would work, as TTT proposed:

```
git rebase --onto origin/feature1 feature1 feature2
```

You would end up with this:

```
* III' (feature2)
* HHH'
* GGG'
* FFF' (origin/feature1)
* EEE'
* DDD'
* KKK (origin/main)
* JJJ
| * III (origin/feature2)
| * HHH
| * GGG
| * FFF (feature1)
| * EEE
| * DDD
|/
* CCC (main)
* BBB
* AAA
```

However, in general, it is *not* wise to keep a local copy of a branch, **specially** if it is not yours... for instance, notice how the 2 branches `feature1` branches (the local and the remote branch) are pointing to different places.... not good. You *might* be tempted to do this to fix it:

```
git checkout feature1
git pull
```

This is a **big** NO-GO because now you want to rebase or merge the commits you have in the **local** `feature1` with the remote one *and* `origin/feature1` **is** the branch, what you had there in the local branch **does not matter** and should be discarded.... so you should do this instead to adjust the pointer:

```
git branch -f feature1 origin/feature1
```

But this is wasted effort, if you ask me.... you should not have a local `feature1` branch in the first place **unless you *really* need it**.... and then, what you should run to do the rebase of your branch would be:

```
git rebase --onto origin/feature1 FFF feature2
```

Or

```
git rebase --onto origin/main FFF feature2
```

Comment: Note the question does state, "I have a feature1 branch created from master." That being said, if `feature1` goes away, or if the local branch gets modified after `feature2` is created, then  this answer is a good elaboration of the Note #2 from my answer.

Comment: Both are good points :+1:

Comment: This answer worked like a charm, thank you. As a personal note, don't forget to start with a fetch. @TTT answer was also very useful to understand what is going on. Thank you to both of you.

Answer (score 2):

If you assume `feature1` is rebased onto `master` before getting merged, then to update `feature2` with the latest `master`, an advanced rebase will work:

```
git fetch
git rebase feature1 feature2 --onto origin/master
```

In words that says:

> Take all of the (non-merge) commits on `feature2` that are not reachable by `feature1`, and replay them, one by one, in order, "onto" `origin/master`.

Notes:

1. "not reachable" is the Git way of saying "not on the branch". If you listed every commit in the history of both `feature1` and `feature2`, most commits would be in both branches except for those new commits on `feature2`. Those commits are the only ones that will be rebased.
2. Note that `feature1` in this case represents the commit on `feature2` that your *local* copy of `feature1` is pointing to. If you don't have a local copy, then inspect your branch to get the commit ID which is the *parent* of the first new commit on `feature2`. (This also represents what `origin/feature1` *used* to point to before it got rebased, and likely subsequently deleted.)

Comment: For an elaboration of Note #2, see [eftshift0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77271072/184546).